# Centrifugal Compressor Flow Rate

Tags: thermodynamics, ideal-gas, flow

For a centrifugal compressor, as found in most turbochargers on internal combustion engines, is there a noticeable change in flow rate versus a naturally aspirated flow rate? In other words, does the pump effectively increase the pressure of the gas only, or does it also increase the flow rate? Really what I'd like to know is how much of the work a turbocharger does goes into increasing the density of the fluid versus how much of it goes into raising its temperature, per the ideal gas law.